# Emoji in iOS app Alerts and Notifications - Xcode/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I'm trying to add an emoji to an alert in Xcode but can't figure it out, any help is greatly appreciated! \xF0\x9F\x98\xB3

Code:

```
if ((self.liveStreamTitle.text?.characters.count) == 0)
        {

            let alertView = UIAlertController.init(title: "Forgot something?", message: "Video Title is empty EMOJIHERE", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: { 

            })

            return;

        }
```

Comment: You need to put the correct representation of the Emoji, good article involving Emoji and push notifications on iOS: https://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/adding-graphics-and-emoji-characters-to-apple-push-notifications/

Comment: Just include the emoji in the middle of your string "I'm happy \ue415" check out Sean's link

Comment: Yep, read the article and also tried simply adding the message: `"Video Title is empty \ue40d"` with no luck.

Comment: Expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you can just add them directly.

```
@IBAction func pressed(sender: AnyObject) {

let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: " NO", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
                //Do your task
}
actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: " YES", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
                //Do your task  
}
actionSheetController.addAction(nextAction)
self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

[image]

You can also do this using Unicode

```
let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "\u{1F425}", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "\u{1F426}", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
```

[image]

Or this using Unicode

```
let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "\u{1F425} YES", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "\u{1F426} NO", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
```

[image]

[Emoji Unicode Chart](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)

Comment: I couldn't add them directly, as I think it's dependent on the IDE or editor you're using (I'm using Atom) but the unicode method works a treat! Thanks! :)